# Vue - Passing data between dynamic components using eventBus?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have **3 Components** in my 'Search' (parent) View; *'SearchForm'*, *'ResultList'*, *'DetailPage'*. I switch from the SearchForm to the ResultList when I have received a response from the backend.

```
<keep-alive>
  <component v-bind:is="currentComponent"></component>
</keep-alive>
```

When a response is recieved in my 'SearchForm' I save it to the searchBus;

```
searchBus.$emit('searchIssue', response.data);
```

Then, in my ResultList I want to retrieve it again and display the results;

```
  mounted() {
    searchBus.$on(['searchIssue'], (search) => {
      this.table_items = search;
    });
  }
```

I display a loading animation (also a component) until the response is fully loaded and the ResultList is displayed.

---

Due to the [Vue lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) everything is working when all components are displayed in one View, as they are already listening when the bus is updated.

**Should I choose a different approach?** E.g. using `v-show` *or* pass the response back to the Parent and inserting it again with a prop (Idk if it would work as not all components have the same props).

**Is there a way to use the Bus anyway ?** And how could it be solved making it one linear hierarchy and still hide the non-relevant components? (SearchForm -> ResultList -> DetailPage)

Answer (score 2):

> Should I choose a different approach?

I thing that is coming time for using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)

> At the center of every Vuex application is the store. A "store" is
>   basically a container that holds your application state. There are two
>   things that make a Vuex store different from a plain global object:
>
> - Vuex stores are reactive. When Vue components retrieve state from it, they will reactively and efficiently update if the store's state
>     changes.
> - You cannot directly mutate the store's state. The only way to change a store's state is by explicitly committing mutations. This
>     ensures every state change leaves a track-able record, and enables
>     tooling that helps us better understand our applications.

Comment: thank you. I thought about that. But everything else is pretty simple or does not need any store, so VueX seems overkill to me. Main part of the application will be these 3 steps; search, display the results and provide a detail-page about every result.